# Issue connecting Django to database

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, pyodbc, django-migrations

I'm currently using python 3.6 and django 2.1.11.  I have a database I'm trying to connect to to make migrations.

Currently my settings looks like:

```
   'Project': {
        'ENGINE': "sql_server.pyodbc",
        'HOST': os.environ.get("DJANGO_DB_SERVER"),
        'USER':  os.environ.get("DJANGO_DB_UID"),
        'PASSWORD':  os.environ.get("DJANGO_DB_PWD"),
        'NAME': "Project",
        'CONN_MAX_AGE' : 600,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
        },
```

I have the settings set in a PowerShell script that I run to set up the env variables.  When I try and make migrations I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'mssql_appuser'. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'mssql_appuser'. (18456); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0)")
```

I went into pyodc base file and added a print statement to see what my connection string looked like:

```
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=db_name;UID=test;PWD=test;DATABASE=Project;MARS_Connection=yes
```

Not sure whats wrong here.  If I attempt to add {} around the driver in the ps1 file the connection comes up like this:

```
DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}}};SERVERNAME=db_name;UID=test;PWD=test;DATABASE=Project
```

which seems incorrect

Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated

Comment: I should add that im able to connect to the db to make queries but this is failing when i attempt to make migrations

Comment: Is the password really `test`? If not, does the real password contain a semicolon or other "funny characters"?

Comment: no those are just dummy values i put here the real password does not contain any weird characters . its weird im able to run the applications, retrieve data from that database. But when i try and make migrations it gives me the error, but the connection is the same, im using the same settings